# Registers management with SSE

Tags: c++, memory-management, sse, cpu-registers

I am currently dealing with SSE for code optimization.

Here is a small part of code (no matter what is done here):

```
            __m128 r_x, r_y, r_width, r_height, width;
            data[0] = (double*)computer->imageIntegralChannels[current0->r_channel].data;
            data[1] = (double*)computer->imageIntegralChannels[current1->r_channel].data;
            data[2] = (double*)computer->imageIntegralChannels[current2->r_channel].data;
            data[3] = (double*)computer->imageIntegralChannels[current3->r_channel].data;

            r_x = _mm_setr_ps(current0->r_x, current1->r_x, current2->r_x, current3->r_x);
            r_y = _mm_setr_ps(current0->r_y, current1->r_y, current2->r_y, current3->r_y);
            r_width = _mm_setr_ps(current0->r_width, current1->r_width, current2->r_width, current3->r_width);
            r_height = _mm_setr_ps(current0->r_height, current1->r_height, current2->r_height, current3->r_height);
            width = _mm_setr_ps(computer->imageIntegralChannels[current0->r_channel].cols, computer->imageIntegralChannels[current1->r_channel].cols, computer->imageIntegralChannels[current2->r_channel].cols, computer->imageIntegralChannels[current3->r_channel].cols);

            __m128 w_x_p = _mm_setr_ps(window_x_pos, window_x_pos + padding , window_x_pos + padding + padding, window_x_pos + padding + padding + padding);
            __m128 w_y_p = _mm_set_ps1(window_y_pos);

            __m128 m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10;

            // First data parameter
            m1 = _mm_add_ps(r_x, w_x_p);
            m2 = _mm_add_ps(r_y, w_y_p);
            m3 = _mm_mul_ps(m2, width);
            m4 = _mm_add_ps(m3, m1);

            // Second data parameter
            m5 = _mm_add_ps(m1, r_width);
            m6 = _mm_add_ps(m2, r_height);
            m7 = _mm_mul_ps(m6, width);
            m8 = _mm_add_ps(m5, m7);

            // Third data parameter
            m9 = _mm_add_ps(m5, m3);

            // Fourth data parameter
            m10 = _mm_add_ps(m1, m7);

            _mm_store_ps(data_p1, m4);
            _mm_store_ps(data_p2, m8);
            _mm_store_ps(data_p3, m9);
            _mm_store_ps(data_p4, m10);
```

I know that SSE implements 16 registers of 128 bits each (with x64 architecture only). In my code here, I am using more than 16 registers at the same time (17 in fact).

Am I wasting time with more than 16 registers used at the same time ? What happened in memory ? Should I always try to manage SSE-code with less than 16 __m128 registers ?

Thank you in advance!
Paul

Comment: Can you please break this out into multiple questions? The question as written is way too broad

Comment: Don't worry about register allocation - make sure you have compiler optimisation enabled (e.g. `gcc -O3`) and let the compiler take care of this.

Comment: Edited!
I tried to compile with -03 instead of -02, and i lose almost 0.20 second (i have seen a lot of topics on that, but here is not the subject). So, the compiler does all the management for us, so cool. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be a problem. Although `__m128` datatypes map to SSE registers, once you enable optimizations in your compiler it should be able to perform smart register allocation with minimal spilling.

If you're worried, you could compile to assembly and check for yourself which registers are being used but from a glance I would imagine there won't be any.